# How to sleep an APR thread?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, apr, thread-sleep

I am using APR library to create portable multi-threading program in C++. Problem is I need to sleep a thread when it is not needed but there is no function mentioned in [manual](http://apr.apache.org/docs/apr/1.4/group__apr__thread__proc.html) to do so.

Do you now a way how to sleep an APR thread without need to use native system functions? I would like to avoid any OS specific code.
Thank you.

Comment: POSIX is hardly "OS specific". I would be very wary of using any library with "portable runtime" in its name. Usually they're not portable (rather full of nasty nonportable OS-specific hacks for every OS their developers tested on) and gigantically bloated.

Comment: APR threads works fine under win32, win64 and Linux where I tried them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you simply want to hand over CPU to other thread, you can use:

```
void apr_thread_yield(void);
```

Otherwise,  you can use:

```
apr_status_t apr_thread_cond_timedwait(
        apr_thread_cond_t *     cond,
        apr_thread_mutex_t *    mutex,
        apr_interval_time_t     timeout  
    );
```

or

```
apr_status_t apr_thread_cond_wait(
        apr_thread_cond_t *     cond,
        apr_thread_mutex_t *    mutex
    );
```

Refer to [here](http://apr.apache.org/docs/apr/0.9/group__apr__thread__cond.html).

Answer (score 2):

...and there is a sleep function in APR too, in "apr_time.h":

```
void apr_sleep (apr_interval_time_t t)
```

Link: [sleep](http://apr.apache.org/docs/apr/0.9/group__apr__time.html#g8ffddc239a3d8051d9972cee080fd761)